# Running transmission-gtk under cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a problem with cron on Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.04.

```
crontab -e
```

I have typed:

```
49 22 * * *     /usr/bin/transmission-gtk
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
pgrep cron
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I've downvoted your question because you never actually asked anything.  Please correct that by editing it to tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem, I think, is that `transmission-gtk` is an interactive X command.  It doesn't make much sense to launch it from your crontab.  In particular, commands invoked by `cron` don't have the `$DISPLAY` environment variable set.  You can launch an X command from cron if you set `$DISPLAY` explicitly:

```
49 22 * * *     DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/transmission-gtk
```

but it's an odd thing to do; in your case, you'll probably just get a new instance of the command every time the job runs.

Your question doesn't indicate what the actual problem is.  What happens, what did you expect to happen, and how do they differ?

I've cleaned up your question's tags and formatting.

Perhaps you should find a non-interactive BitTorrent client.

Comment: Please do not use the answers section to ask questions, use the commands section if clarification is needed

Comment: @Paul: I believe I did answer the question.  The third paragraph explains why what the OP is trying to do won't work, and the fourth suggests a solution.  Are you saying it's inappropriate to ask for clarification along with an answer?

Comment: @Paul: I've edited my answer, putting the actual answer part of it at the top.

Comment: The problem is that answering without knowing the actual issue results in the question getting less attention.  The best approach is get the clarifications first, then provide an answer.

Comment: How about non-interactive x commands? I added "@reboot DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xset b off" to my root crontab but pressing backspace in many programs still makes it beep when there is nothing to erase.

Comment: @Deoxal I'm not sure, but it's likely that the X server isn't running yet when the `@reboot` cron command is run. Consider putting that command your shell startup rather than in crontab.

Comment: Would that be /etc/profile? https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Startup_scripts

Comment: @Deoxal `/etc/profile` is system-wide. I was thinking of something like `$HOME/.profile`, or `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`, or perhaps something else depending on what shell you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the display explicitly

```
49 22 * * *     /usr/bin/transmission-gtk --display=:0.0
```

or

```
49 22 * * *     /usr/bin/transmission-gtk --display=:1.0
```

depending on your display.